# why does my FB.ui dialog request cause a pop-up blocker?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

[In this simple example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453),
when the code runs I don't get a nice "lightbox" dialog, I get a pop-up blocker warning in both IE and chrome.  But I've seen sites that get it to work as a lightbox.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue.  In that example the author assumed you are already authenticated.  You must do this first:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token
```